# Calculating the charge density of a capacitor with one plate tilted

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

Consider a parallel plate capacitor, composed of square plated with length $s$.  The plates are originally length $a$ apart, where $a$ << $s$.  One of the plates are then pivoted in the middle, such that one of the sides are $$ closer and the opposite side are $$ further from the other plate.  Assuming that $$ << $a$, how do I calculate the charge density on the tilted plate, as a function of position?
[image]

Comment: If you are ok with fringe/edge effect approximation, then the charge will be distributed uniformly.

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this, and ask about a conceptual difficulty.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2984